# Send a file from VBA to PHP

Tags: php, vba, http-headers, http-post, server-side

Hello guys I use that code to send a zip file to my server, from here:
https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

I use it to send zip files to my server, but my server-side has a script that can't receive my files, don't know if the problem is from my VBA or my PHP. I will let you with both codes to try to get help from you guys. Much thanks.

```
Public Function pvPostFile(sUrl As String, sFileName As String, Optional ByVal bAsync As Boolean) As String
'Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"
Dim nFile           As Integer
Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
Dim sPostData       As String

'--- read file
nFile = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
    ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
    Get nFile, , baBuffer
    sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
End If
Close nFile

'--- prepare body
sPostData = "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    sPostData & vbCrLf

'--- post
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;"
    .SetRequestHeader "Name", FindLastModified
    .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
    .Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
    If Not bAsync Then
        pvPostFile = .ResponseText
    End If
End With
End Function

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
   pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

My server-side code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$headers = getallheaders();
$input = print_r($_FILES, true);
$sDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It is a part of my server side code. But the problem is here I think, because I can't get my FILE with "$input = print_r($_FILES, true);".
Instead I use it to receive the files, but its not the way it should be:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

$i = strpos($input, "\r\n\r\n");
if ($i !== false)
   $input = substr($input, $i + 4);

file_put_contents('resultado.zip', $input);
```

Comment: Fascinating.  I dunno much about PHP but have you tested your server side code from a web page?  That might help diagnostics.

Comment: Yes, I have a simple webpage to test it, I didn't get any error, but at same time I can't receive my file. Meanwhile if I use the 2nd code I wrote, I can get the file, but it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: What PHP server are you running?

Comment: @SMeaden Meaden I'm not sure. I'm running PHP on a NAS Server.

I'm a rookie in  PHP.